# Capture double click on a cell and get value for ComponentOne's C1FlexGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, componentone, c1flexgrid

I have a **C1FlexGrid** control and that C1Flexgrid control is bound with some data source and now I want to retrieve the data of a particular cell on double click event on a cell. Is there any way to do this?

I try by using

```
 c1FlexGridClassic1_DoubleClick()
```

but this is not giving me a row number or any value.

I tried this by using `CellbuttonClickEvent`, but I don't want this. I want it on the cellDoubleClick event.

#### Code

```
public DataRow ReturnSelectedRow { get { return OrderDataRow; } } //This is property is used for transferring data to other form

private void c1FlexGrid1_CellButtonClick(object sender, C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.RowColEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to  select", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected purchase order" + c1FlexGrid1.Rows[e.Row][1]);
        OrderDataRow = OrderData.Rows[e.Row-1];
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is you code for getting row number?please paste your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read Documentation for `flexgrid`?

there is so many samples of various works with `flexgrid`

here is :

[Flex Pdf Documentation](http://www.componentone.com/newimages/Products/Documentation/WinForms.Flexgrid.pdf)

[Flex Online Documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/)

**Edited :**

use `HitTest` to find if a cell is double clicked

```
void c1FlexGrid1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var ht = c1FlexGrid1.HitTest();

        if (ht.Row!=-1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click on row no--" + ht.Row);
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes i Read all documentation before posting this question but i had not found any solution o it

Comment: `HitTest(e)` Method is not accepting Parameter e . Error occurs invalid argument

Comment: Wow it works but i only use `HitTest()` Method without any argument 
              
     `var ht = c1FlexGrid1.HitTest();`
            `if (ht.Row!=-1)`
            `{`
               `MessageBox.Show("Click on row no--" + ht.Row);`
            `}`